# Does Material UI have an Image component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I used other react components before, they mostly have their own Image component, but I can't find that in Material-UI?

Or is it done via CardMediaAPI? or simply use  tags? Thanks!

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Another option (at least in v5) is to use the Box component and select the underlying html element to be img as given in the example below (copied from [official docs](https://next.material-ui.com/system/basics/) for v5)

```
<Box
  component="img"
  sx={{
    height: 233,
    width: 350,
    maxHeight: { xs: 233, md: 167 },
    maxWidth: { xs: 350, md: 250 },
  }}
  alt="The house from the offer."
  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512917774080-9991f1c4c750?auto=format&w=350&dpr=2"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to MUI and this passed me by in the docs

Comment: I'm kinda new to it too and it took me awhile to notice this as well so I'm glad I could help you avoid the time it took me to figure it out.

Comment: Any idea how you can pass the 'onerror' prop to the image component? Would be nice to be able to set a fallback image on a Box with an img component.

Comment: this has however the disadvantage that Mui unfortunately doesn't set the width/height attribute to the html element directly which is recommended to prevent layout shift after loading see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp.

Answer (score 31):

There is no such specific custom img component avaiable with material-ui.

But you can use the simple html img component inside another wrapper components to create custom img component by your own.
e.g

```
<Paper variant="outlined">
   <img src="url" />
</Paper>
```

Also `<CardMedia/>` component has to be used with in conjunction with `<Card/>` component. 
Another such component which uses image is `<Avatar>` component.

```
<Avatar alt="Example Alt" src="/static/images/avatar.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 23):

Material-ui [recommends](https://material-ui.com/discover-more/related-projects/#image) using [Material-ui-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-image), you have to install it separately but I have really enjoyed using it.
After installing, as expected, it's simply:

```
import Image from "material-ui-image";
...
<Image src="image/src/" />
```

Comment: Material-ui now also recommends mui-image[https://github.com/benmneb/mui-image], which supports MUI v5 (Material-ui-image only supports MUI v4 and below).

Comment: @d2vid That's a useful link. It seemed broken at first, though, because your closing square bracket is part of the link.

Answer (score 10):

Using [mui's Box component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/) is a good starting point. From there one can easily build its own reusable component without the need for another dependency. Try something like:

```
import {Box, BoxProps, } from "@mui/material";

type ImgProps = {
    alt: string;
    src: string;
    // add more HTML img attributes you need
}

export const Img = (props: BoxProps & ImgProps) => <Box component='img' {...props} />;
```

Answer (score 8):

While I am answering this question, the latest version of `MUI` is `5.2.2` and there is no exact image component, but `MUI` had mentioned two third-party provided [image](https://mui.com/discover-more/related-projects/#image) components. One is [mui-image](https://mui-image.surge.sh/) and another one is [material-ui-image](https://mui.wertarbyte.com/#material-ui-image). According to MUI, "`mui-image` is the only MUI image component to satisfy the Material guidelines for loading images" .

You can easily install `mui-image` by following few steps:

Install:

```
npm i mui-image
//or
yarn add mui-image
```

Import:

```
import Image from 'mui-image'
// or
import { Image } from 'mui-image'
```

Use:

```
<Image src="my-image.png" />
```

For details about `mui-image` `props` and more check `npmjs` package docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-image).

Comment: Question, why should I add more dep to my already fat project when I can use Box instead? Notice: I did not ask this question to object you, I am a curious developer who wanted to know more.

Comment: @KasirBarati Using is 'Image' istead "Box" will increase the readability of your code.

Comment: Not 100% convinced - since I can create a custom component and name it Image - but TBH I was looking forward to hear answers that kinda pin point SEO or other stuff like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CardMedia from Material UI as below. Please see the section **Complex Interaction** in [Material UI Example](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/)

```
<CardMedia
    className={classes.media}
    image="/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
    title="Paella dish"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Avatar` component

```
<Avatar variant={"rounded"} alt="The image" src={url} style={{
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  }} />
```

[Docs](https://v4.mui.com/components/avatars/)

Answer (score 3):

Use Box component with component prop:

```
 <Box component="img" src={image} alt={caption} sx={{ height: "50px", width: "auto" }} />
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using [`styled`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#2-reusable-component) to create my own image component:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const StyledImg = styled('img')({});

// Or with a default style

// const StyledImg = styled('img')({
//   display: 'block',
// });

<StyledImg
  src={imagePath}
  alt='my Image'
  sx={{
    width: 50,
  }}
/>
```

[image: Edit MUI Image component]

Answer (score 1):

Use the CardMedia component

```
const [previewImage, setPreviewImage]=  useState<any>();

const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: "image/*",
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
        setPreviewImage(URL.createObjectURL(acceptedFiles[0]));
    },
});

<CardMedia
   component="img"
   sx={{
   height: 233,
   width: 350,
   maxHeight: { xs: 233, md: 167 },
   maxWidth: { xs: 350, md: 250 },
   }}
   src={previewImage}
/>
```

[More details](https://mui.com/api/card-media/)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to go with the `CardMedia` component provided by `@mui/material` instead of using plain HTML tags. You have these abilities and more :

- `onLoad` and `onError` props are used to log messages to the console when the image is successfully loaded or if an error occurs while loading it, respectively. This can be helpful for debugging purposes. Or, you can use your custom functions on these props.
- you can use the `sx` attribute to style your image and at the same time, make styles for different breakpoints.
- you can define the HTML tag type using the `component` attribute
- the `image` attribute is used to display the image
- `alt` attribute for alternative text incase if the image doesn't show up.

Here is a code example on how to use images using the `CardMedia` component

```
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            image={sampleImage}
            onLoad={() => console.log("this is loading")}
            onError={() => console.log("this is error")}
            alt="This is a sample image"
            sx={{
              maxWidth: {
                xs: "100%",
                sm: "500px",
              },
              objectFit: "cover",
            }}
          />
```